# How do I get accordion panel to show in flutter?

Tags: flutter, accordion, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to get a working accordion panel and I found upon researching how to make one, the Get Widget version. However, when I added the code in, everything else in the body went invisible and all that shows is the appbars. I know for sure it's this part of my code specifically because if I take it out, everything else shows up once more. If there's another way to do it that's simple and easy to understand, I would love to know. Once the GF Accordion is out, everything else shows as it should. And yes I made sure the package supporting the GF Accordion was imported and added to the pubspec.yaml file as it should be.

```
Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                border: new BorderDirectional(
                  bottom: new BorderSide(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(112, 112, 112, 0.25),
                      style: BorderStyle.solid
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new GFAccordion(
                      title: 'Requirements',
                      contentChild: Text('No requirements. Just bring yourself! Paint and brushes will be provided.'),
                      collapsedIcon: Icon(Icons.add),
                      expandedIcon: Icon(Icons.minimize),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can set `Container width` to control `width` of `GFAccordion` 
code snippet

```
 Container(
        width: 400,
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:getflutter/getflutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 400,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: BorderDirectional(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(112, 112, 112, 0.25),
                    style: BorderStyle.solid),
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                GFAccordion(
                  title: 'Requirements',
                  contentChild: Text(
                      'No requirements. Just bring yourself! Paint and brushes will be provided.'),
                  collapsedIcon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  expandedIcon: Icon(Icons.minimize),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```